# Is this proof all right?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, induction

In my class we've proven that $\forall m,n,p\in \mathbb{N_{0}}: m=p \implies m\cdot n=p\cdot n$. 
**Remark**: By $\mathbb{N_{0}}$ we mean $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

So  I was wondering whether the foregoing statement's converse is true. Not surprinsingly it's not if $m=1, n=2, p=0$ for instance. Yet, after working out a few more counterexamples I've got cause to believe itr's true provided $p\ne 0\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ (I'm a rookie so it's not immediately obvious to me). That is, I'd like to show that$$\forall m,n,p\in \mathbb{N_{0}}; p\ne 0: m\cdot p=n\cdot p\implies m=n$$

For this proof we harness the following lemma: $\forall k\in \mathbb{N_{0}}:k+1\ne 0$.

*Proof lemma:* By way of contradiction, let's suppose $\exists k\in \mathbb{N_{0}}: k+1=0$. Since $k+1$ is the succesor of $k$. Our assumption means $0$ is the succesor of $k$. Yet $0$ is the succesor of no natural number. Hence, from this absurdity we've established our lemma.

*Proof* **(By induction on $p$)**. Let $m,n\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ be fixed.

**Base case:** Let's observe that $p=1\implies (m\cdot p=n\cdot p\implies m=n)$ is trivial because $\forall s\in \mathbb{N_{0}}:s\cdot 1=1\cdot s=s$.

**Induction hypothesis:** Let $q\ne 0\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ and assume \begin{align*}m\cdot q=n\cdot q\implies m=n\tag{$i$}\end{align*}Given that $q+1\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$, we may take for granted that $m\cdot (q+1)=n\cdot (q+1)$. In particular for $0\ne q+1\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ from $(i)$ and what we took for granted, we conclude $m=n$. Thus far, $\forall m,n,q\in \mathbb{N_{0}}:(m\cdot q=n\cdot q\implies m=n)\implies \Big(m\cdot (q+1)=n\cdot (q+1)\implies m=n\Big)$.

Therefore, by the principle of mathematical induction $\forall m,n,p\in \mathbb{N_{0}};p\ne 0: m\cdot p=n\cdot p\implies m=n$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: May I ask which grade are you in? It seems like you are surprised by your discovery (so perhaps you don't know about rational numbers, otherwise this problem would be easy), but for some reason you know about induction which is usually taught in high school and have a good understanding of using quantifiers...

Comment: OP, I think you mean the converse, not contrapositive, statement. Also, what do you mean when you say "we may take for granted that ..."? To me it seems you are trying to argue that since the induction hypothesis holds for any $q \in \mathbb{N_0}$, you replace $q$ with $q+1$. But this is not quite right; yes it's true that you may assume the induction hypothesis for an arbitrary $q$, but once you do so, that object is fixed for the induction argument. You cannot "take it for granted" in that sense.

Comment: @masiewpao I didn't quite replace. I argued that since $q\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ was arbitrary and we have another natural number $q+1$ I could conclude what was assumed for $q$ but in particular for this other number because, after all, I thought that what since we know something for an arbitrary natural number for any natural number like $q+1$ we can conclude what stated in our induction hypothesis.

Comment: @StefanOctavian Is my proof wrong? :/

Comment: @masiewpao In the book I'm reading "Handful of Mathematical induction" there's no part where the author precises that the induction variable is fixed in the induction hypotehsis? What does it mean for a variable to be fixed? Not varing? What does begin fixed imply?

Comment: I thought that was what you meant, but no, you cannot do that. You are trying to prove the statement $\forall k \in \mathbb{N_0} (P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1))$. Here $P(k)$ is your statement $m\cdot k = n\cdot k \rightarrow m = n$. Notice that when you assume $P(k)$ is true, yes, $k$ is an arbitrary value, but you must prove for THIS arbitrary value that $P(k+1)$ is true. What you are doing is assuming $P(k+1)$ to prove $P(k+1)$.

Comment: You are assuming that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0 (P(k))$ is true in your proof, and then trying to use universal instantiation on $q+1$. But that's not what induction says! Induction requires you to use that IF $P(k)$ is true for some particular $k$, then $P(k+1)$ is also true, for the same $k$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127186/discussion-between-hanny-boy-and-masiewpao).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stylistically, your proof is a little rough, and I think working on improving your writing would be useful.

And the last line of your proof confuses me. You start by assuming $m \cdot (q+1) = n \cdot (q+1),$ and that $m\cdot q = n\cdot q$ implies $m=n.$ Then you just say $m=n.$  You need some intermediate step here--why does $m \cdot (q+1) = n \cdot (q+1)$ give you that $m=n$?

I would suggest using the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is an ordered set to prove your claim, by arguing that if $m < n$ then $m \cdot (q+1) < n \cdot (q+1),$ and if $m > n$ then $m \cdot (q+1) > n \cdot (q+1).$

Comment: I thought that because $q\ne 0$ was an arbitrary natural number and since I found another natural number $q+1$ in particular I could conclude what was assume for $q$ which is $m\cdot q=n\cdot q$ but this time for $q+1$. Can't I?

Comment: In class we still have not discussed the order of $\mathbb{N}$. I wouldn't know how to argue from that angle.

Comment: @HannyBoy Your first comment I cannot parse at all. Your proof is wrong as written. The only property of multiplication you use is that $n \cdot 1 = n.$ If I defined a new operation $a \star 1 = a$ and $a \star b = 0$ for all $b \neq 1,$ this proof would work just as well here, even though the theorem is false. You are not justifying yourself fully.

Comment: Is it false even though we suppose $p\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ is not $0$?